# Induction Proof from Thomas Judson book on abstract algebra

Tags: induction, integers

I'm trying to prove $$^n\sqrt{a_1\times a_2\times...\times a_n}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k, \quad a_i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$$
by Induction. The case is true for $n=1$ so I assumed true for $n=k$. I then tried \begin{align*}
^{k+1}\sqrt{a_1\times a_2\times ...\times a_{k+1}} &\leq \enspace ^{k}\sqrt{a_1\times a_2\times...\times a_k}\times ^{k}\sqrt{a_{k+1}} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i \times ^{k}\sqrt{a_{k+1}}
\end{align*}
and have tried playing around with the algebra to try and get the desired result but cannot get it to work. Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We want the $a_i\ge 0$.  This is the famous arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality (AM-GM). Many proofs, including a clever induction proof by Cauchy.

Comment: See for example [Wiki: proof of AM-GM by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_induction)

Comment: The result is usually proved for $a_i$  non-negative reals. Perhaps the restriction to $a_i$ non-negative integers would let us give other proofs.  That would be kind of interesting.